# Correct way to create a k8s secret?

Tags: kubernetes, sequelize.js, kubernetes-secrets

I am not sure if I'm interpreting the output from my container correctly, but I am seeing the following output from sequelize in the logs:

```
Nates-MacBook-Pro:k8s natereed$ docker logs 1a3e6141d050
...
(node:36) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionError: password authentication failed for user 
"postgres
"
```

It *appears* there is an extra newline character in the username, which should be "postgres". The database is configured with the environment variable $POSTGRESS_USERNAME (yes, I know it is mispelled, it is from another author).

```
src/config/config.ts:    "username": process.env.POSTGRESS_USERNAME
```

I shelled into the running container and checked that the environment variables are correctly set:

```
root@backend-feed-75c4f97d6-9tp2f:/usr/src/app# echo $POSTGRESS_USERNAME
postgres
root@backend-feed-75c4f97d6-9tp2f:/usr/src/app# echo $POSTGRESS_PASSWORD
...
root@backend-feed-75c4f97d6-9tp2f:/usr/src/app# echo $POSTGRESS_DB      
mydb

...
```

To create the secret and then apply, I ran:

```
echo "postgres" | openssl base64
(edit env-secret.yaml)
kubectl apply -f env-secret.yaml
```

The contents of the secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: env-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  POSTGRESS_USERNAME: cG9zdGdyZXMK
  POSTGRESS_PASSWORD: ...
```

Is this not the correct way to create the k8s secret?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo "postgres"` includes a newline at the end of the string which is also included in the encoded secret. Instead, use:

```
echo -n "postgres" | openssl base64
```

The `-n` flag suppresses the newline.

Answer (score 7):

The simple option:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: env-secret
type: Opaque
stringData:
  POSTGRESS_USERNAME: myapp
  POSTGRESS_PASSWORD: supersecret
```

`stringData` takes plain strings instead of base-64 encoded `[]byte`s.

Comment: Is there a reason to use Base64 other than to deal with whitespace or other characters that could break the yaml formatting? I copied my YAML from an example. Obviously there is no security in Base64, not sure what the point is.

Comment: It’s not uncommon for Secrets to include binary data, like Java keystore files for example. But if your data doesn’t include that, then nope!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this enhances my understanding.